# Google Map position marker

Tags: google-maps, gps, maps

I want to develop a simulator for driving, something that simulates a GPS movement.
I'm using google maps for this, i managed to make the marker move around my route, but i have other problem now.

I have:

- start location
- start time
- end location

I want to calculate position based on time elapsed from start time. and display the marker on correct location, every time some user opens the page.
Need to calculate lat, long somehow and change start position every time the page is loaded.

Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: I believe it's against the Terms of Service to use Google maps like a GPS

Comment: Yes there is a way to make it work.  Calculate the distance traveled along the route and place the marker there.  If you have code that moves the marker along the route, you are most of the way there.

Comment: Tina, this is for demonstrative usage only, i don't make this application public or something

Comment: geocodezip, i already place the marker there(current position when somebody is on the page), the problem is that i need to calculate in time, even if someone didn't opened the page.